# Looping multiple feature classes in python for ArcGIS 10

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.0, modelbuilder

I currently have a large list of feature datasets and dbf tables in a geodatabase. I would like to join each shapefile with its matching DBF file using the "Make Query Table" tool and then "Copy Features" to produce a new shapefile with specified fields.

I am trying to automate this process so I don't have to manually select field names for each set of data (output table would use the same fields). By using the Iterate Datasets in ModelBuilder, I was hoping to do this. However, the Make Query Table will not connect to the geodatabase and still requires me to plug in a specific table.

Does anyone know I can use looping to run this process?

Are there any similar examples using python?

Example of Geodatabase:
AAA1_part1.shp
AAA1_part1.dbf
AAA2_part2.shp
AAA2_part2.shp
.....
.....

Comment: I think the first, most relevant question is how are your `tables` named?  What is unique about them that would allow someone, with a script to say that for a particular `featureclass` or `shapefile`, join this particular `table` to it?

Comment: They all feature the same three letter code followed by a number that categorizes each: AAA1_part1.shp with AAA1_part1.dbf. It's only a matter of changing around a single numeric value.

Comment: can you post the operation you'd like to iterate? i'm having a hard time figuring out what you're trying to do. if you post a concrete workflow, i can take a crack at iterating it.

Comment: So my model takes a feature class (AAA1_part1_Streets) and a DBF table (AAA1_part1_Traffic) and does a "Make Query Table" and joins them by a LINKID. I would like to iterate the "Make Query Table " pulling all Traffic DBF and Streets feature classes in my file geodatabase and creating joined feature classes for all pairs. The issue is I can only iterate feature classes, but I can't seem to do both feature classes and DBF files